# Librosa Spectogram vs Matplotlib Spectrogram

Tags: matplotlib, signal-processing, fft, librosa, spectrogram

I know spectrogram can be plotted using different functions of the different libraries in python. In matplotlib, plyplot plots spectrogram directly using time-series audio data but librosa first applies short Fourier transform on data before plotting spectrogram.

But I am still confused between two.

Please tell me the detailed difference between

```
1.librosa.dispay.specshow() 
2.matplotlib.pyplot.specgram()
```

I have searched the internet a lot but couldn't find any relevant information though.

Answer (score 0):

According to `librosa` [documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/main/auto_examples/plot_display.html), all `librosa` plotting functions are depends on `matplotlib`.

> All of librosa’s plotting functions rely on matplotlib. To demonstrate everything we can do, it will help to import matplotlib’s pyplot API here.